# Are heroku and AWS the same?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku

I have been planning to build a website through Node. But I really have no idea where to start. Upon my reasearch, I have seen various articles saying that I must try heroku in order for me to have a better understanding of node.

For my future development I want AWS to be my main server. The reason I'm asking this is so that if I begin my tutorial learning in heroku, I  will be sure that it would be the same environment in AWS. Thanks in advance

Comment: No, they're not the same. Heroku runs _on_ AWS. Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk service is similar to Heroku but it uses different conventions. I'm not writing an answer since this is likely too broad for Stack Overflow. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thanks by the way!